# AEM - How to cache model for page scope?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have a sling-model that needs to do some *costly* operations at initialization. These are related to the page scope, meaning based on `currentPage` properties. Hence it would make sense that the model gets initialized only once per page call.

I found a nice article regarding this at [how to call sling model only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204646) where they are setting the `cache` property of the `Model`-annotation to true.

But this unfortunately only works per resource.

So setting the `cache=true` property the model gets initialized for every component that calls it via `data-sly-use`. It only helps wenn calling `data-sly-use` in the same component (resource), but that's not helpful.

Can I somehow have the model cached for the entire lifecycle of the *page*-request?

Comment: you should consider removing the logic that does not need to be called every-time the component is initialized, from the component model; maybe use a service and call it conditionally. also you can set attributes to request with page scope.

Comment: What did you mean with "set attributes to request with page scope"? Setting this in a service? Unfortunately it's necessary having the operations' result in each component, as they're always using the data.

Comment: nevermind the scope part, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SlingHttpServletRequest](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html) is a wrapper around HttpServletRequest and supports setAttribute and getAttribute methods provided by servlet api.

Setting attributes:

```
slingRequest.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, myobject);
```

Retrieve:

```
//check for null
MyClass myobject = (MyClass) slingRequest.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
```